# How can i implement Webdriver / PageObjects / Pagefactory in Java in a way that can be generally applied

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

Here is my attempted implementation understanding of PageObjects/Pagefactory as applied to Webdriver:

```
1. Create the following structure in eclipse

--> com.example.qa.pageobjects 
     --> LoginPage.java

Every class in this package has something like: 

@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "logonName")
    private WebElement logonNameField;

and the Methods, call Webelement, and call methods on them, like:

logonNameField.sendKeys("username");

Which are called from ScenrioTests.

     --> HomePage.java (i go there after i login)
     --> Page.java (abstract)

--> com.example.qa.setup
    --> Browser.java
    --> FirefoxBrowser.java (Code specific to FFox)
    --> ChromeBrowser.java (Code Specific to Chrome)

--> com.example.qa.test
    --> Scenario1234.java 
    --> Scenario2345.java
```

These Scenario Classes instantiate the PageObjects, and Call methods in them, while the Browser setup is only called Once per test run.

Now the question is:

1. Should i declare a method like below and call Pagefactory ?

public MyPage method() {
        Call the Methods like Login() etc
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, MDNSLoginPage.class);
    }

1. Or, Should i Call the same PageFactory from default Constructor
2. Is my understanding / implementation correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I kind of follow your no 1 approach . I will try to answer by illustrating my implementation but I am not sure whether it would be useful for your purposes.
 I have a baseTest class that I load with common methods that can be used across my test classes . (eg. instantiate browser, open login page etc)

```
abstract class TestBase {
//somewhere
protected static LoginPage goToLoginPage(){
   driver.get(loginPage);
    return  PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
} 

protected static void startBrowser(Browser browser){}
   //implemntation
  }
```

Then, in my test classes that inherit the abstract class  I use it in the following manner

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup(){
  //use a common method to start browser    
  startBrowser(Browser.FIREFOX);
    }

@Test
public void canLogInToHomePage(){
//start my test like this
LoginPage loginPage =goToLoginPage();

}
```